# Responsive two columns layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

The first link in google about "responsible two column layout" is the thing i wanted to do, but reversed (content on the right column). Apparently it is also the wrong way to create the columns since the wrapper doesn't really "wrap". The internal div are absolute, while the wrapper is relative. This gives problems because the footer doesn't really go at the bottom of both colums if they aren't full of text. What is the best correction I can make to it? Also I hope this link will go above that link or other people might be on the same situation.
I realise linking it here will make it higher though :/

```
 .columnsContainer, footer, header { position: relative; margin: .5em; } 
.rightColumn { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }
```

link : http://codepen.io/johnstonian/pen/guhid

Comment: How wrapper doesn't really wrap? give me more codes

Comment: @HermanNz you should check the link. there is a lot of code. Basically the .columnsContainer is before the <footer> in the html. The .rightColumn is inside the .columnsContainer. If you leave the .leftColumn empty but you fill the rightcolumns, you will see the <footer> just after the .columnscontainerends, which means it will overlap the content of rightcolumn

Comment: .columnsContainer indeed doesn't wrap both columns since rightcolumn is in absolute position. this can be only fixed by using: float and fixed width without absolute set in position. your problem is the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291610/two-column-css-layout-without-having-to-specify-the-right-column?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with the absolute position is to convert some values of both columsn as follows:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .leftColumn {margin-left: 19.5em;}
.rightColumn{width: 18.75em; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
}
```

Comment: I don't see a difference. I think the problem is that the footer starts after the left column finished. My solution should be probably to have the left cloumn at least as big as the right one.